# laravel muti lavel association

Tags: laravel, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I have 3 tables and these table are not according laravel

```
job_post Table
  job_post_id
  name

job_functional_area Table (has many with job_post table and belongsTo with functional_area) 
  job_functional_area_id
  job_post_id
  functional_area_id

functional_area
  functional_area_id
  name
```

now I want to fetch job_post functional area

Relation like this job_post > job_functional_area > functional_area

In cakephp we use contain in laravel i don't have an idea.

I have try Has Many Through but it will not work in this condition. Please help me

Models

```
class JobPost extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'job_post';
     protected $primaryKey = 'job_post_id';

}

class JobFunctionalArea extends Model {
     protected $table = 'job_functional_area';
     protected $primaryKey = 'job_functional_area_id';  
}


class FunctionalArea extends Model {
     protected $table = 'functional_area';
     protected $primaryKey = 'functional_area_id';  
}
```

Comment: Post your models, your exact query and the error you are receiving please.

Comment: If you don't want to put in any effort, why do you expect others to help you?

Comment: sorry sir i will post this

Comment: I have posted Model

Answer (score 0):

Your models should look something like this.

```
class JobPost extends Model {
        protected $table = 'job_post';
        protected $primaryKey = 'job_post_id';

        public function jobFunctionalAreas() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\JobFunctionalArea');
        }
}

class JobFunctionalArea extends Model {
        protected $table = 'job_functional_area';
        protected $primaryKey = 'job_functional_area_id';

        public function jobPosts() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\JobPost');
        }

        public function functionalArea() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\FunctionalArea');
        }
}


class FunctionalArea extends Model {
        protected $table = 'functional_area';
        protected $primaryKey = 'functional_area_id';

        public function jobFunctionalAreas() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\JobFunctionalArea');
        }
}
```

Also in the relations you can add your own custom $primaryKey.